# UICollectionView not scrolling when stat scrolling from UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to create dynamic UICollectionView for my application using code below, the problem is that when i start scrolling from CollectionViewCell it's not scrolling but when i start scroll from outside it works fine.

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10

let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
registerCell(collectionView: collectionView)
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self

collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

_scrollView.addSubview(collectionView)
```

[You can Watch video](https://youtu.be/5SNuoLsFrWo)

CollectionViewCell's properties

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the touch-down event is passed to the collection view (scroll view) correctly? Make sure the cells don't have a custom touch-down event (e.g. tap gesture recognizer, or touchesBegan method without calling the super inside) and also make sure the collection view delays content touches, it's a common mistake to uncheck it and forget it, and then try to understand why a view is not handling touches properly, but its children are.

Comment: You are right i was using SwipeCollectionViewCell. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the cells don't have a custom touch-down event (e.g. tap gesture recognizer, or touchesBegan method without calling the super inside) and also make sure the collection view delays content touches, it's a common mistake to uncheck it and forget it.